# Can I create a workflow that will not an item in a list from being visible once it has been selected once by it's ID number in another list

Tags: workflow

I have createad 2 custom lists, one attaches an ID number to each new item, the other picks up this ID number and allows the user to select the ID number they want. what I want to do is create logic in a workflow that will 'grey out' items in the first list once they have been selected, via their ID number, in the second list.

I have done this in SharePoint 2003 but can't seem to work out 2010.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cindy,

What you can do is create a workflow for the second list [that is the list which is using first list as a lookup field, I am assuming you have a lookup field], in that workflow update the item of first list [the item that is selected] and update the Lookup Item and set Status field as Selected.. [You will be needing a column in first list, as Status]

Now you can create a List View Web Part where using CONDITIONAL FORMATTING you can Grey Out the item, or complete row! Below are some posts for Conditional Formatting:

[1](https://www.jrjlee.com/2011/06/conditional-formatting-of-list-views.html)
[2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160926130058/http://sp365.co.uk:80/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-2010-conditional-formatting/)
[3](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216062242/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)

I hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for the response. What I mean by 'grey out' is that once the item has been selected once, the workflow will stop it from showing up in the modfied views I have of the list but will still show up in the 'all items' part.

Comment: Sorry I still didn't get it.. If you want the selected items not to show up in modified views, you can filter them on Status field I mentioned above! and in All Items you will not be applying any filter which will bring all the items..?